# page going blank on clicking a link

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

When i open my site in Firefox and click in a link, static things like the sidebar and the menu are always there, they don't blink or something. Only the rest of the content changes.

On the other hand, in Chrome, when i click in a link, the whole page goes white for some milliseconds and then, the whole page appears.

Is there any way(javascript, css, etc) of forcing chrome to do the same firefox does?

Comment: Without some code, how should we know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: atleast give your site link!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, this is called a page refresh. There are a few ways to prevent a page refresh, and the method you choose will depend on your scenario and size of your website.

One of the methods is using jQuery. You write your content in a different, hidden container (i.e. a `<div style="display:none" />` in the same page and use jQuery to switch the contents.

Demo
http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/